# C++ implicit constructor with member's argument list?

Tags: c++, c++17, implicit-conversion

Apologies if I am not using C++ nomenclature correctly. I also tried searching StackOverflow and Cppreference but couldn't find information about this case.

Let's take the following piece of code.

```
struct Foo{
    vector<int> vec; 
    Foo(vector<int> inp) : vec(inp){};
};

struct Bar {
    Foo foo; 
    Bar(Foo inp) : foo(inp) {};   
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = {1,2,3};
    Foo foo(vec);
    Bar bar1(foo);

    Bar bar2(vec);
}
```

So, I have `Bar` which has a member `Foo`. `Foo` is supposed to be initialised with a vector, while `Bar` takes `Foo` as a constructor argument. Nothing unusual here.

Surprisingly, I noticed that I am allowed to do `Bar bar2(vec)`. Looks like there exists an implicitly defined constructor which could look like `Bar(vector<int> vec) : foo(vec){}` .

This is quite surprising to me. From what I know, c++ only implicitly generates default, move and copy constructs, as well as destructors. In this case, it looks like it generates a constructor which mirrors the member's argument list and passes it to the member's constructor. Is it what happens in reality? Could you please provide some more information about this behaviour?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean

Comment: `Foo(vector<int> inp)` is a non-`explicit` constructor with exactly 1 argument. This defines an implicit conversion from `vector<int>` to `Foo`. The compiler sees that `Bar` has a constructor that wants a `Foo`, it sees you provided a `std::vector<int>` and it sees an implicit conversion that it can use. The code works because the compiler quietly adds an intermediary steps, it does not define any new constructor for `Bar`.

Comment: Okay, I haven't looked at explicit keyword while trying to explain this. Makes sense now, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo` has a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) taking a `vector`. In `Bar bar2(vec);`, `vec` is implicitly converted to a temporary `Foo` via the converting constructor, then the temporary `Foo` is passed to the constructor of `Bar` as an argument.

You can mark the `Foo` constructor as `explicit` to prohibit the implicit conversion:

```
struct Foo{
    vector<int> vec; 
    explicit Foo(vector<int> inp) : vec(inp){};
};
```

BTW: `Bar::Bar(Foo)` is a converting constructor, too.

Comment: Makes sense, exactly what I needed! I haven't heard about converting constructors, will give it a read. Thank you!